# iOS : CMPedometer / Framework Error when install in device, it's run in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, pedometer

I am getting error in CMPedometer, with i am install my app in iPhone device, i have iPhone 4s and iPhone 6s both have same issue.

Here with attached screenshot of issue

[image]

Project Link : https://github.com/versluis/Pedometer

in both device have iOS 9 grater OS.

Comment: which xcode are you using ?

Comment: Version 8.1 (8B62)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue, after 4 hours of hack....

Getting issue in my XCode SDK - CoreMotion.framework was corrupted.
(In my last 9 years of experience this is the first case of XCode corrupted)

Corrupted CoreMotion.framework Screen Shot.

[image]

Repair CoreMotion.framework Screen Shot. (Copied from other system that framework and replace here)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Once try by adding `CoreMotion.Framework` in your project from `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` under `general` or `Build phases` tab under targets of project settings!

And make sure that you are adding `NSMotionUsageDescription` in your `info.plist` file!

Comment: Setting the `NSMotionUsageDescription` is mandatory for +iOS10. If you don't app would crash!